# Why we needs to chages brake pads?

Tags: wheels

Why needs to changes brake pads in my car every times because i have changes my brake in before 2 times but still facing noise problem in car.

Comment: Hello! If you could tell us some more about your car it would help us help you.

Comment: So you have a problem with noise while braking, and replacing the pads hasn't helped?

Comment: Did you have the rotors machined or replaced? Or did you put new pads on a used rotor?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Without much detail supplied, my reply is general : brake pads need to be changed as the friction material wears out. If not fitted correctly, they can chatter or vibrate in use or as first applied causing noise. Correct fitting helps reduce this.